# Reading arrays within arrays of a json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, datatables

I am building a site which will output data from a JSON file into a table, but I am having issues getting the content to output. This JSON file is generated from another site which surfaces documentation, while my site just creates a table for easy searching of those docs.

SAMPLE JSON for 2 docs:

```
    [{
        "title": "SampleTitleA",
        "lang": "en-US",
        "lastEdition": "2020-07-28",
        "version": "1.0",
        "metadata": [
        {
            "key": "sampleKeyA1",
            "label": "sampleLabelA1",
            "values": ["sampleValueA1"]
        },
        {
            "key": "sampleKeyA2",
            "label": "sampleLabelA2",
            "values": ["sampleValueA2"]
        }]
    },
    {
        "title": "SampleTitleB",
        "lang": "en-US",
        "lastEdition": "2020-07-28",
        "version": "1.0",
        "metadata": [
        {
            "key": "sampleKeyB1",
            "label": "sampleLabelB1",
            "values": ["sampleValueB1"]
        },
        {
            "key": "sampleKeyB2",
            "label": "sampleLabelB2",
            "values": ["sampleValueB2"]
        }]
    }]
```

I am using DataTables for this (https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html) and have tried doing what it describes. It doesnt really cover reading arrays within arrays though.

To select an array within an array I have tried to follow the datatables example and done the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        //sort on col 3 desc
        "order": [3, 'desc'], //order by date
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "ajax": {
            "type": 'GET',
            "dataType": 'json',
            "lengthChange": true,
            "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            "url": "jsonlocation",
            "deferRender": true,
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        
        "buttons": [ 'copy', 'excel',
            { extend: 'colvis', columns: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]}
        ],
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        "columns": [
            { data: 'metadata.15.values.0', "defaultContent": "-" },
            { data: 'title', "defaultContent": "-" },
            { data: 'metadata.16.values.0', "defaultContent": "-" },
            { data: 'lastEdition', "defaultContent": "-" },
            { data: 'lang', "defaultContent": "-" },
            { data: 'version', "defaultContent": "-" },
            { data: 'readerUrl', "defaultContent": "-" },
            { data: 'readerUrl', "defaultContent": "-" },
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [5],
                "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<a href="' + data + '">Click</a>';
                }
            },
            {
                "targets": [7],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": true
            }
        ]
    });
}
);
```

A table is created, but not populated, and shows no errors in console.
Has anyone any experience using dataTables for this purpose?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your `datatable` code.

Comment: You mention that the JSON in your question represents a _single_ document. So I assume the actual JSON consists of _many_ such objects in an array - is that correct? So, for example what would the complete JSON look like for 2 documents? We would need to see that overall structure to provide relevant guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Ive updated to include 2 sample docs in array

Comment: Thank you - that helped. Answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON data structure is an array - everything is contained in a `[...]` - therefore DataTables can iterate over this array to generate its table rows.

Here is an example with everything removed from your code except for the column `data` definitions (and column titles):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: {
          // my test URL:
          url: 'http://localhost:7000/sample2',
          dataSrc: ''
        },
        "columns": [
          { title: 'Title', data: 'title' },
          { title: 'Language', data: 'lang' },
          { title: 'Key', data: 'metadata[0].key' },
          { title: 'Label', data: 'metadata[0].label' },
          { title: 'First Value', data: 'metadata[0].values[0]' }
        ]
    } );

  } );

</script>
```

This generates a table which looks like this:

[image]

How does this work?

By default, DataTables expects the JSON structure to be as one of the following:

1. An object containing an array of other objects:

```
{ "data": [ {...},{...},... ] }
```

2. An object containing an array of arrays:

```
{ "data": [ [...],[...],... ] }
```

In both these cases, the array has a name (in this case `data`).

In your case, as already noted, your data is just a plain array of objects:

```
[ {...}, {...},... ]
```

Because the array has no name, we need to use `dataSrc: ''` in our DataTable definition, to indicate this lack of a name.

After that, you can reference the values you need to display, for example `data: 'title'`.

For the `metadata` section, that is itself a label referring to an array of objects:

```
"metadata": [ {...} ]
```

However, in this case the array only contains one object. We can refer to that first object in the metadata array using `[0]` - and then we can access the values in that object - for example, by using: `data: 'metadata[0].label'`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this helps you out.

```js
var data = {
    "title": "SampleTitle",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "lastEdition": "2020-07-28",
    "version": "1.0",
    "metadata": [
    {
        "key": "sampleKey1",
        "label": "sampleLabel1",
        "values": ["sampleValue1"]
    },
    {
        "key": "sampleKey2",
        "label": "sampleLabel2",
        "values": ["sampleValue2"]
    }]
}

var result = { data: data.metadata[1].values[0], "defaultContent": "-" }
console.log(result);
```